# How to float box on top of map

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

In the [this](http://jsbin.com/gist/c7dabcad61f8c4398130305a2035decd?html,output) jsbin how do I float the div with class box on top of the map?

Here is the css I'm using for the box and body.

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I think [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) can help you on this one

Comment: I don't see a thing with class `box`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anil, it would be nice if you could add some explanation so that the asker can understand and learn from your answer :). Check out our article on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: no need to set `position:relative;` on `body` because it already is by default.